# Вызов системных команд из node.js и отображение их результатов

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gulp

Пытаюсь отдать через gulp команды в системную консоль:

```
  const { exec } = require("child_process");
  var git_commant = "cd django-hamlpy & git add . & git commit -m \""+ desc +"\" & git push";

  exec(git_commant, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });
```

В целом вроде работает. Но почему-то сообщения у меня отображаются в stderr. Почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так же само сообщение обрезается. Обычно при удачном выполенении таких команд в консоли вывод такой:

```
Enumerating objects: 35, done.
Counting objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 3.74 KiB | 273.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), completed with 11 local objects.
To https://github.com/Sanshain/django_hamlpy.git
   9629024..8c0deab  master -> master
```

Comment: Я не уверен, но может `stderr` это вовсе и не ошибка и всегда существует.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, Я всё же думаю, что проблема в  `isatty()`. Или как вы предлагаете прогресс бары раскладывать в конвейере? Ах, там так команда выписана... (см. комментарий ниже)

Comment: А вы точно не путаете `&` с `&&`?

Comment: @0andriy, что такое `issaty()`? У меня такого нет

Comment: @0andriy, не знаю. Всегда `&` нормально работало

Comment: Я тоже гвозди всегда микроскопом забивал...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean

Comment: @0andriy, а... ну так у меня скрипт для windows-ского батника, а не линуксового шела

Comment: Увы, из поста этого не видно было. Тогда, как и в ответе ниже, проблема в `isatty()`. В windows как-то тяжко с этим вызовом.

Comment: @0andriy, ну так-то на скрины обратный слэш был...

Comment: @0andriy, у меня по этому слову `isatty()` только С++ гуглится что-то...

Answer (score 3):

Сообщения отображаются в `stderr` потому что их и отправили в `stderr`. В вашем случае это делает "Git".

И обрезаются сообщения тоже из-за него. При клонировании репозитория он динамически отрисовывает в консоль нечто вроде прогресс-бара, в результате чего поток много раз очищается вместе со всеми сообщениями